# Getting a list of installed packages with tllocalmgr (Arch Linux/Manjaro)

Tags: packages, texlive, linux

Using the texlive-localmanager, how do I get a list of installed packages?

Alternatively, if the specified task is not feasible, is there another recommendable TeXLive package manager that runs on Manjaro (based on Arch Linux)

Comment: Just as a side note: According to the Arch Wiki, if you run Manjaro you don't run Arch Linux :)

Comment: @Skillmon Quite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed TeXLive via the Arch repositories, you can look up the installed packages in the files located in:

```
/var/lib/texmf/arch/installedpkgs/*.pkgs
```

On Manjaro there might be similar files or the same in a different (or same?) path (I don't know, because the Manjaro-Wiki includes no article about its TeXLive).

Comment: Yup, I can confirm that this location contains the lists in Manjaro as well, although getting a list in the program itself would have been preferable. Thanks

Comment: @tillyboy On Arch, this will get you a list of installed Arch packages (or, maybe, installed Manjaro packages). It will not get you a list of installed TeX packages in the sense of 'package' used by `tlmgr`, for example. Each Arch package includes a bunch of TeX Live packages. You need to figure out which TeX packages are in which Arch package to get a meaningful list.

Comment: @cfr inside those `*.pkgs`-files there should be lists of which CTAN-packages are included!

Comment: There will be a list of *files* but there is probably no list of TeX *packages*. Not all packages correspond in simple ways to paths. (And you will need to sort and reduce to eliminate multiple listings for most which do.)

Comment: The `*.pkgs`-files are lists of the CTAN-packages included in that pacman-package. There is a list of packages inside those files. Do I have to say it more often? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
tlmgr info --list --only-installed
```

if you need only the number of packages:

```
tlmgr info --list --only-installed | wc -l
```

Comment: At least on Arch this doesn't work (`--list` and `--only-installed` are both unknown options). Also on Arch there is no `tlmgr`, the program's name is `tllocalmgr` there. The same seems to be true on Manjaro, because the question states "tllocalmgr".

Comment: @Skillmon Another good reason not to use Arch's TeX Live rather than upstream's. Personally, I think it would be quite reasonable for Arch not even to package it: upstream's installer is more consonant with the Arch Way. You cannot get anything remotely like a vanilla TeX Live installation this way.

Comment: @cfr might be true (well most likely it is). But managing through pacman is convenient, therefore I do understand if people choose this route (as I did, out of convenience).

Comment: @Skillmon It is more convenient to install, possibly, but less convenient to manage as discussions like this one show.